# Git: updating branches when core error found

Tags: git

There are 2 different projects based on common core in separate directories, and 2 branches in Git repository for each one. While developing first project, big core's error (many lines, many files) was found and corrected.
What is right way to update second project?

Comment: Is the layout like this: Common/, Project1/, Project2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When branch1  Common/ is updated and committed, switch to branch2
Use cherry-pick to carry the changes in Common/

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know about cherry-pick.

Comment: Cherry-pick http://hades.name/blog/2010/03/03/git-your-friend-not-foe-vol-4-rebasing/